# Publish to the App Store TestFlight track and failed with code: 64

Tags: ios, react-native, azure-pipelines, app-store, testflight

I am using `Azure pipeline` to deploy app on `test flight` before I was able to upload the build but now I am getting following error.

I am new to `react native iOS` any help with this issue will be helpful.

**Locale Machine configuration**

- xcode version Version 13.2.1 (13C100)
- Mac Book version 11.6.6 (20G624)

I have tried some changes in `azure-pipelines.yml` file but didn't worked, don't know what and where the changes need to be done.

> azure-pipelines.yml

```
trigger:
- main

pool:
   vmImage: 'macOS-10.15'

variables:
   - group: App Variables

steps:
  - task: NodeTool@0
  inputs:
      versionSpec: '12.19.0'
  displayName: 'Install Node.js' 
  - script: yarn install
  displayName: Install Dependencies
  - task: Xcode@5
   inputs:
      actions: 'build'
      configuration: 'Release'
      sdk: 'iphoneos14.5'
      xcWorkspacePath: 'ios/Safety.xcworkspace'
      scheme: 'Safety'
      packageApp: true
      archivePath: 'output/archive'
      exportPath: 'output/package'
      exportOptions: plist
      exportOptionsPlist: 'ios/ExportOptions.plist'
```

> Error reported

```
   Error uploading ipa file: 
   ERROR ITMS-90725: "SDK Version Issue. This app was built with the iOS 14.4 SDK. All 
   iOS apps submitted to the App Store must be built with the iOS 15 SDK or later, 
   included in Xcode 13 or later."

   [Transporter Error Output]: The call to the iTMSTransporter completed with a non-zero 
   exit status: 1. This indicates a failure.
   ##[error]Error: The process '/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/bin/fastlane' failed with exit code 1
   ##[section]Finishing: Publish to the App Store TestFlight track
```

> When I am changing sdk version to 15.2 getting following error

```
 Task         : Xcode
 Description  : Build, test, or archive an Xcode workspace on 
 macOS. Optionally package an app.
 Version      : 5.200.0
 Author       : Microsoft Corporation
 Help         : 
 
 /usr/bin/xcodebuild -version
 Xcode 12.4
 Build version 12D4e
 /usr/bin/xcodebuild -sdk iphoneos15.2 -configuration Release - 
 workspace /Users/runner/work/1/s/ios/Proxus.xcworkspace -scheme 
 Proxus build CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED=NO | 
 /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/bin/xcpretty -r junit --no-color
 xcodebuild: error: SDK "iphoneos15.2" cannot be located.
 ##[error]Error: /usr/bin/xcodebuild failed with return code: 64
 Finishing: Xcode
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your pipeline file specifies `macOS-10.15`. This image has [Xcode 12](https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/blob/main/images/macos/macos-10.15-Readme.md).

You need Xcode 13 to build with the iOS 15 SDK.  Specify either `macOS-latest` or `macOS-11`.  This image contains Xcode 13.

Comment: changing `macOS-latest` and `iphoneos15.2` solved my problem